# Delay text field validation message in Angular form

Tags: angular, forms, validation

I have the following Angular form:

```
<form class="needs-validation" [formGroup]="loginForm.formGroup!" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" novalidate>
  <!--*! Email -->
  <div class="mb-3">
    <div class="form-floating">
      <input id="inputEmail" type="email" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': invalidEmail() }"
        formControlName="email" (input)="resetInput('email')" placeholder="Email address" spellcheck="false">
      <label for="inputEmail" class="form-label text-dark">Email address</label>
    </div>
    <div class="text-danger" *ngIf="invalidEmail()">
      <small>{{ invalidEmail() }}</small>
    </div>
  </div>

  ...

</form>
```

Which in the browser looks something like this:
[image]

As you can see I also have a `invalidEmail` function which returns a string with an error message if the email is invalid (empty string if the email is valid)

```
invalidEmail() {
  if (this.loginForm['email']?.touched) {
    if (this.validationErrors['email']?.message) {
      return this.validationErrors['email'].message;
    }
    if (this.loginForm['email']?.invalid) {
      return 'Invalid email address';
    }
  }
  return '';
}
```

The problem I have is that as soon as I leave the email field (leaving it blank) the error message is shown:
[image]

This results on the links for **Forgot your password?** and **Sign up** to move down. So if the user's cursor is in the email field and tries to click in the **Forgot your password?** link, the link will be moved down preventing the click to happen.

I thought that maybe delaying the display of the error message could solve the issue, but I haven't found a way to get it to work.

Any suggestions on how that could be achieved or workarounds to solve this accessibility issue?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you call the invaildEmail during submit and call the api only when valid and if invalid throw the error that might solve the problem